# Display images on the browser with map method using url's coming from an API

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display two images on the browser based on url's I got from an API.
So,

1. I have fetched the data
2. run a map method that will run all over the array that I got, and whenever it running into an image it inserts it into a empty div using innerHTML.

and this is what i got:

[image]

HTML:

```
   <body>
        <button id="new-deck">New Deck, Please!</button>
        <button id="draw-cards">Draw</button>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <div id="container-card"></div>
    </body>
```

JS:

```
    let deckId
let container = document.getElementById('container-card')
function handleClick() {
    fetch("https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/?deck_count=1")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            deckId = data.deck_id
        })
}

document.getElementById("new-deck").addEventListener("click", handleClick)

document.getElementById("draw-cards").addEventListener("click", () => {
    fetch(`https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${deckId}/draw/?count=2`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data.cards.map(item =>container.innerHTML += `<img src=${item.image}/>`))      
})
```

Comment: _"Unfortunately it didnt work"_... what did it do instead? How did it _not work_? Do you have any errors reported in your dev-tools _Console_?

Comment: Is `deckId` supposed to be interpolated into the URL? Ie `fetch(\`https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${deckId}/draw/?count=2\`)`

Comment: Url should be enclosed into quotes

Comment: Thanks @Phil I have added  the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. you are not submitting `deckId` during image fetch api call.
2. image `src` url must be enclosed into quotes, otherwise backslash is added to the end of the url:

```js
    let deckId
let container = document.getElementById('container-card')
function handleClick() {
    fetch("https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/?deck_count=1")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            deckId = data.deck_id
        })
}

document.getElementById("new-deck").addEventListener("click", handleClick)

document.getElementById("draw-cards").addEventListener("click", () => {
    fetch(`https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${deckId}/draw/?count=2`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data.cards.map(item =>container.innerHTML += `<img src="${item.image}"/>`))      
})
```

```html
        <button id="new-deck">New Deck, Please!</button>
        <button id="draw-cards">Draw</button>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <div id="container-card"></div>
```

Every time you are dealing with API calls, make sure you check what data you receive before you minimalistic your code with one-liners.
and use `catch` for promises to catch any errors that might occur.

Comment: Worked like magic! thanks!

Comment: This is the solution of my tutor: https://ibb.co/kXshVS6
and this is also the reason i didnt use "" in the first place, as you can see he doesn't use map method but he also doesn't wrap the content inside the src with ""

Comment: If you are using XHTML then it's [required](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Doctypes_and_markup_styles) that attributes to be enclosed in single or double quotes. But also note, your tutor's code has a space before the slash.